# Laplace transform and indefinite integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals, laplace-transform

Is the following statement OK (when the Laplace and integral are well-defined)?

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-0x}f(x)dx=\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}(0)$$

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes that looks fine with the caveats you have

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @NinadMunshi, the problem is that most of time the region of convergence to the Laplace Transform is $Re(s)>0$, right...? :/

Comment: That's not always true. $e^{-t}$, for example, has a region of convergence $\operatorname{Re}(s) > -1$

Comment: @NinadMunshi, thank you! Maybe you would like to post your comments as answer.